# Create a compositing node 2D Vector from individual x & y components

Tags: compositing-nodes, mathematics

A node I want to use requires it's inputs to be Vectors. However, video tracking nodes output [separate x & y components](http://puu.sh/lOeAe.png), not a Vector. I can't seem to find any node that allows me to create a Vector from these components within the node editor.

Am I missing something?
What would you recommend as a method of generating the vector input?

Comment: Does the *Converter* > *Combine RGBA* node work?  At least in Cycles this is the [same thing](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31376/5705) as a *Combine XYZ* node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *Combine RGBA* node. This is because in practice [color and vector inputs are more or less the same](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33915/599).

[image]

Comment: Ha Ha, I almost tried that but thought, "No, there has to be a better way". Thanks.

Comment: @Glyph heh, yeah it's pretty strange. They added a "combine XYZ" node to cycles for just this reason (it's identical to the combine RGB node).