# How to model a light source using a spectral distribution curve for the color

Tags: modeling, light, color

My previous attempt was unclear so I'm rephrasing the question:

I'm making a promo video for a certain type of lighting and at one point, I'd like to show the difference in the spectral power distribution (**see graph below**) of the light output for each type of bulb.  In other words, ***I want to use the SPD to color the light emitted by the bulb into the room based on wavelength and output power***.

I have the SPD, I just need to use it somehow to color the emission source.  This is all I can think of but it's not exactly mathematical and I'm not sure it really captures a realistic representation and I don't know if it just basically averages the colors together:

[image]

It produces this light:

[image]

But I would rather have the emitted light follow a curve similar to this if at all possible:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to consider using an engine such as LuxRender or Maxwell which will directly support SPDs via a text file or the like.

Comment: That's very interesting, I've never used anything but Cycles, I'll look into it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [wavelength](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/converter/wavelength.html) and [blackbody](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/converter/blackbody.html) nodes?

Comment: I have used the Blackbody node but I didn't even know about the wavelength node... checking it out...

Comment: Hmmm... would be neat to have an input to the wavelength node to determine the Q of the color selection but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish this you would require a wavelength to XYZ conversion, and then from XYZ to sRGB / REC.709 primaries conversion.

Make sure that you obtain linearized RGB values from your wavelengths. If you are using normalized wavelengths, display linear (0.0 to 1.0) would suffice.

Comment: 1.) When you say XYZ to sRGB conversion, do you just mean to ensure the display color space is in sRGB (i.e. there's no sRGB conversion node unless you mean combine RGB)?   
2.) How will using the XYZ channels help to plot a curve over the spectrum with certain high Q peaks?

Comment: Also, according to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31375/is-separate-rgb-identical-to-separate-xyz  .... the RGB and XYZ nodes are identical except for nomenclature.

Comment: Uh... Not spatial XYZ. CIE 1931 XYZ. You won't be able to use Blender to achieve this.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Blender can't do this even for a simulation?

Comment: If you were careful and know the precise values to set up in nodes as well as the intended meaning and how to use the results, I suppose a very driven person could do it. It would be hell however. :)

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the info